# SqlCeCommand throwing exception

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-ce

This command keeps throwing an exception at my C# program, however seems to work fine in SQL query builder.

```
using (SqlCeCommand cf = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT Lname FROM stats WHERE
    (score = (SELECT MAX(score) FROM stats))", cn))
```

There was an error parsing the query.

> Token line number = 1, Token line offset = 41, Token in error = SELECT

Comment: Which sql DB you use?

Comment: Does SqlCeCommand support this kind of subquery?

Comment: "however seems to work fine on SQL query builder." - but are you running this against CE?

Comment: Likely the reason. CE Is a tiny embedded db and they HAD to cut out a lot. If you want a real server, install express. That has most of the features (ok, all except the enterprise stuff). CE is just limited.

Comment: scheien is right. SQL Server CE does not support subqueries that return a scalar value. Arif's answer works because the `IN` keyword tricks the parser into thinking that the subquery returns a record set.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that SqlCeCommand support this kind of sub query.

Are you are running against a Compact Edition runtime, and a server version when testing with Management Studio? As in lots of functions are available in the server version, but only a  subset is available in the compact edition.

[Check out this post on MSDN forum.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/df8c5ea3-13b6-4925-8177-068b75c16ee4/multiple-select-statements-is-sql-compact?forum=sqlce)

Answer (score -1):

Please Try it

```
using (SqlCeCommand cf = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT Lname FROM stats WHERE
    score IN (SELECT MAX(score) FROM stats)", cn))
```

Comment: This will work, although probably worth adding an explanation as to why, an answer with no explanation is not very useful at all (hence no upvote yet) - SQL Server CE will not parse subqueries that return a scalar value, there is no problem when the subquery returns a set (or is parsed as if it could return a set, i.e using `IN` instead of `=`)